# How to update one table in MySQL after insertion in another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two table first is "employee_details" second is "attendance_rule"

1. employee_details

   ```
   e_code  |  e_name  |  e_type
   01      |  Ram     |  Regular
   02      |  Shyam   |  Contract
   03      |  Mohan   |  Regular
   ```
2. attendance_rule

   ```
   e_code  |  e_type  | casual_leaves 
    01     | Regular  |      7
    02     | Contract |      6
    03     | Regular  |      7
   ```

I have manually insert values in "attendance_rule".

Now the problem is that when the attendance rule changes in the organisation. The user has to manually update the `casual_leave` coloumn for all the employees.

What I want is that when an employee details are added in `employee_details` table , the entry in the `attendance_rule` table should be automatically made having `e_code` and `e_type` same as `e_code` and `e_type` of `employee_details` table and `casual_leaves` equals to the `casual_leaves` of the same `type` of employee.

I think that a trigger should be used here.
but I dont know how to use trigger for this condition i.e. for the entry of casual leaves.
Please help me...how should I do that? Is there a way to do it other that trigger?

Comment: Do you need a trigger? Is the casual_leaves value different for every employee, or just for every employee type?

Comment: @Stobor casual_leaves values are same for employees of same type. For example - All Regular type employees will be having 8 casual leaves and all Contract type employees will be having 4 casual leaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't need a separate entry in `attendance_rule` for every employee, just for every employee type, so you don't need a trigger at all.

Create `employee_details` like you suggested:

```
    e_code  |  e_name  |  e_type
    01      |  Ram     |  Regular
    02      |  Shyam   |  Contract
    03      |  Mohan   |  Regular
```

But create `attendance_rule` with only the rules for each type:

```
    e_type  | casual_leaves 
   Regular  |      7
   Contract |      6
```

If you need to find the number of casual leaves for a particular employee, join the two tables:

```
select 
      e.e_code, 
      e.e_name, 
      e.e_type, 
      a.casual_leaves 
 from employee_details e 
        inner join attendance_rule a on e.e_type = a.e_type
```

to get

```
    e_code  |  e_name  |  e_type   | casual_leaves 
    01      |  Ram     |  Regular  |      7
    02      |  Shyam   |  Contract |      6
    03      |  Mohan   |  Regular  |      7
```

And if you want to make it as easy to use as a table, you can create a view:

```
create view emp_all_details as 
select 
      e.e_code, 
      e.e_name, 
      e.e_type, 
      a.casual_leaves 
 from employee_details e 
        inner join attendance_rule a on e.e_type = a.e_type
```

Now you can simply say: `select * from emp_all_details` to get:

```
    e_code  |  e_name  |  e_type   | casual_leaves 
    01      |  Ram     |  Regular  |      7
    02      |  Shyam   |  Contract |      6
    03      |  Mohan   |  Regular  |      7
```